# How to find the mean peaks in positive axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, mean, amplitude

I wish to find the mean of all peaks from the positive axis in Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1]

I tried
`pks = findpeaks(y);`
  but it includes some negative value.

How to filter out the negative peaks and keep the positive peaks?

Comment: You can remove the negative values by doing `pks(pks<0) = [];`. You may also want to check out the [`envelope`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/envelope.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define the term 'mean of the peaks'. One way to quantify an effective 'strength' of a fluctuating signal is using the root-mean-square ([RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)) value. 
Example:

```
>> X = rand([10000, 1]) - 0.5;
>> mean(X)
ans =
   -0.0031
>> rms(X)
ans =
    0.2896
```